# Get the ID of each record in a dynamically created form through button click C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that returns all appointments of a certain doctor. What I want to know is how to get the ID of each returned data.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve. 
 1. Create controls dynamically based on the number of appointments on this particular doctor. 
 2. To edit each appointments - but in order to do that. I need to get
    the ID of a specific panel through a click event. What I have right
    now is.. I only get the ID of the last record –

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server = localhost ;Database = mica_userclient_laravel; username = root;");
// MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server = sql12.freemysqlhosting.net; Database = sql12221392; Uid=sql12221392; Password=5gZN1uN6NX;");
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT users.id, 
        users.fname, users.mname, users.lname, 
        appointments.created_at, appointments.id, 
        appointments.status 
        FROM users, appointments 
        WHERE users.id = user_id 
          AND appointments.status = 0 
          AND appointments.client_id = '" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
//textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[1].ItemArray[5].ToString();

//login.quantity = textBox2.Text;

//label4.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[1].ItemArray[4]).ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");
//label7.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[1].ItemArray[4]).ToString("h:mm tt");
//label3.Text = dt.Rows[1].ItemArray[3].ToString() + ", " + dt.Rows[1].ItemArray[1].ToString();

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{

    textBox[i] = new TextBox();
    textBox[i].Name = "n" + i;
    textBox[i].Text = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString();
    textBox[i].Visible = true;
    textBox[i].Location = new Point(txtboxX, txtboxY);
    txtboxY += 25;
    panel[i] = new Panel();
    panel[i].Name = "n" + i;
    panel[i].Width = 793;
    panel[i].Height = 56;
    panel[i].BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
    panel[i].Location = new Point(panelX, panelY);
    panelY += 80;




    label[i] = new Label();
    label[i].Name = "n" + i;
    //label[i].Parent = panel[i];
    label[i].Font = new Font("Century Gothic", 14);
    label[i].Height = 22;
    label[i].Width = 250;
    label[i].ForeColor = Color.Gray;
    label[i].Text = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString() + ", " + dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();
    label[i].Location = new Point(labelX, labelY);

    label1[i] = new Label();
    label1[i].Name = "n" + i;
    //label[i].Parent = panel[i];
    label1[i].Font = new Font("Century Gothic", 14, FontStyle.Bold);
    label1[i].Height = 22;
    label1[i].Width = 250;
    label1[i].ForeColor = Color.Gray;
    label1[i].Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[4]).ToString("MMM dd, yyyy - h:mm tt");
    label1[i].Location = new Point(label1X, label1Y);

    imgbtn[i] = new BunifuImageButton();
    imgbtn[i].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    imgbtn[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    imgbtn[i].ImageLocation = @"Image\edit.png";
    imgbtn[i].Width = 46;
    imgbtn[i].Height = 38;
    //imgbtn[i].ImageActive = @"Image\edit2.png";
    imgbtn[i].Location = new Point(imgbtnX, imgbtnY);
    imgbtn[i].Click += new EventHandler(bunifuImageButton1_Click);


    this.Controls.Add(panel[i]);
    this.Controls.Add(label[i]);
    this.Controls.Add(imgbtn[i]);
    this.Controls.Add(textBox[i]);
    panel[i].Controls.Add(label[i]);
    panel[i].Controls.Add(label1[i]);
    panel[i].Controls.Add(imgbtn[i]);

    gumanaka = textBox[i].Text;
}
```

Comment: Sorry.. I need to get the ID of the particular record that was created dynamically.

I only get the last record.. is there any way to get the ID of a specific panel?

Comment: What do you mean by `ID`?

Comment: the appointments_id from the appointments table.

Comment: You are looping on the rows of your table. In which column of this table is stored the ID that you want to retrieve? Is that values shown in the TextBox?

Comment: Since i'm joining 2 tables.. The column that my ID is stored is on the 5th ItemArray..

The values are shown dynamically, for each record.

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

1. Create controls dynamically based on the number of appointments on this particular doctor.

2. To edit each appointments

- but in order to do that. I need to get the ID of a specific panel through a click event.

What I have right now is.. I only get the ID of the last record

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48996727/edit) to provide additional information as what you have written is not clear at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataRowView to get the column of the table when clicked on it..

For an example on a selection changed event of your table you can use this:

```
DataRowView dr = table_name.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
int id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["appointments_id"]);
```

Or in your case if its the 5th element:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(dr[4]);
```

just check the value with

```
MessageBox.Show(dr.ToString());
```

Comment: I'll try this later. Thank you so much!